# SonataPageBundle with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony-sonata, sonata

somebody has installed  succesfully  sonata page bundle with mongodb?
We have a lot of trouble and seems that sonata page is not supported except with orm.

Tnx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct there is no support for mongodb on PageBundle. Feel free to send any relevant PR to improve the support.